# Setting up Network File Share on raspberry pi, need to restart nfs-kernel-server each time the system is started

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfs

I am building a 4 node raspberry pi cluster,so one head node, and 3 compute nodes, following this tutorial: http://makezine.com/projects/build-a-compact-4-node-raspberry-pi-cluster/

And I am trying to use the NFS protocol to share data from a usb stick, what I found is that when I shutdown the pi's and start them the next day, I have to go to the head node and run:

```
   sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

before I can mount the drive on the other nodes. Similarly, from the tutorial it was recommended to update the /etc/fstab file so that the drive is mounted when the node is started. But I'm finding that because I need to run the command above before I can mount the drive, it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this problem?

As an update, I was asked to show the status after I had rebooted the system. I did find a warning that the portmapper was not running.

```
     nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2016-06-05 20:18:02 UTC; 4min 0s ago
     Process: 444 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

     Jun 05 20:18:02 rpi0 nfs-kernel-server[444]: Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon....
     Jun 05 20:18:02 rpi0 nfs-kernel-server[444]: Starting NFS kernel daemon: nfsd
     Jun 05 20:18:02 rpi0 nfs-kernel-server[444]: Not starting: portmapper is not running ... (warning).
     Jun 05 20:18:02 rpi0 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Kernel NFS server support.
```

Comment: Post the result of running `systemctl status nfs-kernel-server` on the server.  Note it's possible to check for any other failed services using `systemctl status` / `systemctl` (look for red highlighting in the latter).

Comment: before the manual restart of the service, obviouslly.

Comment: @sourcejedi I updated the question to show the status you asked for.

Comment: is rpcbind running? it needs to be, so if not that could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests [this is a problem with some raspbian update](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=125483).

if you look in dmesg / journalctl?  This would be something to check for.  I think you should have seen a similar indication if you thought to check the status of portmapper... if you knew that relevant service had been renamed to rpcbind :).  (Although it should have shown up in the overall list of failed services which I suggested to check).

```
[    3.494252] systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
[    3.506955] systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
[    3.519265] systemd[1]: Found dependency on rpcbind.service/start
[    3.531550] systemd[1]: Found dependency on network-online.target/start
[    3.544316] systemd[1]: Found dependency on network.target/start
[    3.556489] systemd[1]: Found dependency on dhcpcd.service/start
[    3.568562] systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
[    3.580419] systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job rpcbind.service/start
[    3.594361] systemd[1]: Job rpcbind.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
```

The last post in the thread is a nice hacky workaround.

It looks like another workaround would be to remove dhcpcd, if you don't need a dhcp client.

It looks the same as this Debian bug (believed fixed): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788191